# Why is the Enable Wireless button greyed out and unselectable?

Tags: 12.04, wireless

The 'enable wireless' button on the top right is greyed out and I am unable to click it and my wireless won't work anymore. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You did try the hardware switch?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It was enabled, I clicked to disable it (because that causes it to refresh the network list) and it won't let me enable it anymore.

Answer (score 6):

You can try that:

1. turn on wireless switch
2. in a terminal windows execute the below command 
    `sudo rfkill unblock wifi`
3. reboot
4. in a terminal windows execute the below command
    `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up`
5. enable wireless in NetworkManager

Worked for me!

Comment: Great suggestions, especially the wireless switch. I always forget that it exists.

Answer (score 3):

After multiple reboots, I still could not get "Enable Wi-Fi" to be selected on Ubuntu 16.04 on my PC. After some searching, I found the following procedure solved my problem.

1. `sudo rfkill list`

   this is to find out if your wireless device is hardware/software blocked
2. `sudo rfkill unblock all`

   this is to unblock every wireless devices, including the WiFi and bluetooth (if there is one)
3. `sudo vim /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state`

   and change from false to true on line "WirelessEnabled=true"or something
   like that.
   This seemed to be the key step for fixing my problem; it appeared that network-manager inquired this file during reboot to restore its state, i.e., if Wi-Fi was grayed out before the reboot, it will stay grayed out after reboot.
4. `sudo reboot`

`sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service` wasn't able to get network-manager to use the modified state file.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: for me `sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service` is sufficient.

Comment: İ had to edit and then lock that file to make it work after the restart by: chattr +i /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state

Answer (score 1):

if your hardware switch is on or if you do not have a hardware switch in the first place,

during boot-up go to the **BIOS** menu and check whether the ***Enable Wireless at startup*** is ***Enabled***.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem after suspending xubuntu 20.04 with wifi disabled. When I came back, 'Enable wi-fi' was greyed out and I couldn't turn it back on.

I tried

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

That makes sure it's not blocked.

Then the order of steps is important:

```
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager.service

sudo vim /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
```

and change from false to true on line "WirelessEnabled=true". Then:

```
 sudo systemctl start NetworkManager.service
```

Then everything goes back to normal and wifi works. It seems network manager writes this state as false when it stops, but reads it when it starts, so a simple restart isn't enough.

In addition, I noticed that sometimes, despite these steps, I also needed to kill and restart nm-applet to get the options to not be grey.

```
pkill nm-applet
nm-applet &
disown
```

There is a bug to report in here somewhere!

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04 using xfce.

Answer (score 0):

This command solved for me:

```
sudo nmcli n on
```

`nmcli` is the network manager client, `n` stands for *networking* and `on` means that the command must turn networking back on.